# Unable to move file via perl CGI

Tags: apache, perl, unix

I have a perl script to move a file from one folder to another folder. When I run this manually it works fine. But when I execute it from the browser I am unable to do. Getting error message.

I knew it is related to CGI environment access right. But how to add that permission to my perl script. I gave already 777 permission to that file and folder, but still cannot. Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use File::Copy;

print "Content-type: application/json\n\n";
my $query = new CGI;
my $name = $query->param('name');
#$name = "WVID21WAAA110200";

my $sdir = "/disk1/advisories/input/unread";
my $tdir = "/disk1/advisories/input/read";
my $file = $sdir."/".$name;
my $tfile = $tdir."/".$name;
my $f = 0;

print "[";
if (-e $file && -f $file)
{
        move($file,$tfile) or $f=1;
        if(($f==1)){
        print "{\"status\":\"failed\",\"message\":\"Access Denied\"}";
        }else{
        print "{\"status\":\"success\",\"message\":\"File moved\"}";
        }
}else{
        print "{\"status\":\"failed\",\"message\":\"Invalid file\"}";
}

print"]";
exit 0;
```

Comment: Most likely it is a question of file permissions of the file target and its folder, not of the permissions for the perl script. Keep in mind that the CGI execution probably runs under a different user account. And also take care to remove those `0777` permissions from the script again. That is _highly_ insecure and _never_ requried.

Comment: My CGI script is ruuning as apache user. Even I added 777 to files and folders.

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. Any output from the `move` command to `stderr` there?  (Provided you log that...)

Comment: Thanks @arkascha, It's because of the destination path folder doesn't have execute permission. I added nad it works fine now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I mentioned the target folder permission in my first comment :-) But once more: you really should take care to limit the permission set to what is actually required. Do not leave files writable world wide, especially not in a web environment. But great that you sorted out your issue!

Comment: If you have a solution, you should post that as an answer. Self answering is not just allowed, but encouraged in that scenario.

Comment: "Getting error message." In that case it would be really helpful to include that error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the destination path folder doesn't have execute permission. I added nad it works fine now. – Rajesh